# Julia functional performance confusion

Tags: performance, julia

I am new to Julia, and as my first stab at a mildly nontrivial program wrote the below, which computes the divisor sigma functions for all numbers in a range from 1 to N - the divisor sigma function sigma(k, n) computes the sum of kth powers of divisors of n (if k is 0, it is simply the number of divisors). Since sigma(k, n) is a multiplicative function of n, we write it as below (this, in principle, should be far more efficient than factoring each integer in our range):

```
using Primes

thefunc(i) = (a::Int, b::Int)-> sum(BigInt(a)^(k*i) for k in 0:b)

function powsfunc(x, n, func)
    bound = convert(Int, floor(log(n)/log(x)))
    return Dict{Int, Number}(x^i => func(x, i) for i in 0:bound)
end

dictprod2(d1, d2, bd)=Dict(i*j=> d1[i]*d2[j] for i in keys(d1), j in keys(d2) if i*j<bd)

function dosigma(k, n)
    primefunc = thefunc(k)
    combfunc = (a, b) -> dictprod2(a, b, n)
    allprimes = [powsfunc(p, n, primefunc) for p in primes(n)]
    trivdict = Dict{Int, Number}(1=>1)
    theresult = reduce(combfunc, trivdict, allprimes)
    return theresult
end
```

The good news is that the above works. The bad news is that it is horrifically slow, with `dosigma(0, 100000)` taking ten minutes of CPU time, and consing 150GB(!). Question is: why?

Comment: You're iteratively building up a dictionary that's not strictly typed. I can't think about a less performant code. Your code cannot be type-stable because what comes out only be known to be a `Number`, and you should use a structure with less indirection. In general, the less strict the data type the less performant. FWIW Python classes are essentially non-strictly typed dictionaries, so that should explain a lot.

Comment: @Igor I'm really no expert in performance optimization, so I don't write this as an answer, but I think the bottleneck may just be the `BigInt`s; [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/phipsgabler/7b245cdf840fd026f3dc24d93793a3dd) is pretty fast if you use `Int`s, but still needs 3.5 min and 50 GiB for n = 100000 with `BigInt`s. The downside is that you can only use really small k then, of course...

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Thank you, but what would you suggest instead? Using lists of tuples (more natural in this application) is faster, but not a huge amount faster.

Comment: Can you update it with your lists of tuples code? If those tuples are all the same type then it should be type stable (check that with `@code_warntype`). If it's still slow then you may just be running into a bottleneck due to arbitrary sized integers, which is just a fundamental computing issue since any arbitrary-sized number representation inherently has overhead. But make sure that's the case!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my go at it.
First `powsfunc`:

```
function powsfunc(x, n, func)
    bound = Int(floor(log(n)/log(x)))
    final_dict = Dict{Int, Int}()

    for i in 0:bound
        final_dict[x^i] = func(x,i)
    end

    return final_dict
end
```

I changed the dictionary to be `{Int, Int}` type. This is more precise than `{Int, Number}` so it should be slightly more performant - as Chris pointed out in the comments. But actual testing didn't show any difference in performance.

The other change is that rather than using a comprehension to define the `Dict` I'm assigning the dictionary elements one by one. This reduces the memory estimate - measured by `@benchmark powsfunc(10, 1000, thefunc(0))` from 1.68KiB to 1.58KiB. Not 100% sure why this is. I think I read somewhere that the `Dict` definition is not completely polished yet, but I can't find that reference. Maybe someone more knowledgable can shed light on why this is?

Big gains can be made at `dictprod2`. Again, thanks to Chris for pointing this out. Defining the `Dict` with `Int` types makes a huge difference.

```
function dictprod2(d1, d2, bd)
    res = Dict{Int, Int}()

    for (key1, val1) in d1
        for (key2, val2) in d2
            key1*key2>bd ? continue : true
            res[key1*key2] = val1 * val2
        end
    end 

    return res
end
```

I benchmarked this with:

```
primefunc = thefunc(0)
b1 = powsfunc(2, 1000, primefunc)
b2 = powsfunc(5, 1000, primefunc)

@benchmark dictprod2(b1, b2, 1000)
```

The results with your code were 9.20KiB allocs with a median running time of 5.513 μs. The new code used only 1.97KiB and median running time of 1.68μs.

The final function, I kept pretty much the same as I didn't find any ways of improving it.

```
function dosigma(k, n)
    primefunc = thefunc(k)
    combfunc = (a, b) -> dictprod2(a, b, n)
    allprimes = [powsfunc(p, n, primefunc) for p in primes(n)]
    trivdict = Dict{Int, Int}(1=>1)
    theresult = reduce(combfunc, trivdict, allprimes)
    return theresult
end
```

Checking with `@benchmark` all of this takes `dosigma(0, 1000)` from 81ms and 28MB to only 16ms and 13MB.

I also ran `dosigma(0, 100000)` and got 85s and 52GiB of allocs.

I'll leave it open to the experts to add to this answer. I'm sure someone more knowledgable could make this even faster.

Comment: Unfortunately, the values of the dictionary are not guaranteed to be `Int`s... (in fact, certainly won't be, if k is big enough, still very cool, though!

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Changing `powsfunc` to `{Int, BigInt}` and the others to `{Int, Number}` still gives improvements over the original code in terms of time: 62ms instead of 81ms. But that means your bottleneck is more than likely to be `BigInt`. :(

Comment: I think your answer is a lot more informative than mine and I'm questioning whether mine will add anything to the conversation. Shall I remove my answer?

Comment: Speaking for myself, your answer is helpful in helping me learn the language!

Answer (score 0):

I have done some more thinking/coding/profiling (mostly on the very nice [JuliaBox](https://www.juliabox.com) platform), and the one line summary is:

**Julia is not LISP**

which means that programming in functional style will only get you so far.

Now, let's get to the code (which is what we want to see anyhow). First, here is the reference "stupid" implementation:

```
using Primes

function sigma(k, x)
   fac = factor( x)
   return prod(sum(i^(j*k) for j in 0:fac[i]) for i in keys(fac))
   end

allsigma(k, n) = [sigma(k, x) for x in 2::n]
```

On JuliaBox (also on my laptop) it takes about 40 seconds for k=0, n=10000000. An astute reader will note that this will break for largish k because of overflow. The way I get around this is by replacing the function by:

```
function sigma(k, x)
   fac = factor( x)
   return prod(sum(BigInt(i)^(j*k) for j in 0:fac[i]) for i in keys(fac))
   end
```

This takes 131 seconds for the same computation (95 seconds on my desktop) so a little more than a factor of 3 slower. By contrast, the same computation in *Mathematica* done as:

```
foo = DivisorSigma[0, Range[10000000]] // Timing
```

takes 27 seconds (on the desktop), which indicates that, most likely, *Mathematica* first checks that the computation can be done in fixnums, and then does it in the obvious way.

Now we move on to the "intelligent" implementation. The working hypothesis here was that Julia is not at functional language level for operating with data, so, with that in mind, I avoided the creation and destruction of dictionaries for the following code:

```
using Primes

thefunc(i) = (a::Int, b::Int)-> sum(BigInt(a)^(k*i) for k in 0:b)

function biglist(n, func, thedict)
bot = Int(ceil(sqrt(n)))
theprimes = primes(bot, n)
    for i in theprimes
        thedict[i] = func(i, 1)
    end
    return theprimes
end

function powsfunc(x, n, func, motherdict)
    bound = convert(Int, floor(log(n)/log(x)))
    res = Int[]
    for i in 1:bound
        tmp = x^i
        push!(res, tmp)
        motherdict[tmp] = func(x, i)
    end
    return res
end

function makeprod(l1, l2, nn, dd)
    res = []
    for i in l1
        for j in l2 
            if i*j <= nn
                dd[i*j] = dd[i] * dd[j]
                push!(res, i*j)
            end
        end
    end
    return vcat(l1, l2, res)
end

function dosigma3(n, k)
    basedict = Dict{Int, BigInt}(1=>1)
    ff = thefunc(k)
    f2(a, b) = makeprod(a, b, n, basedict)
    smallprimes = reverse(primes(Int(ceil(sqrt(n))) -1))
    bl = biglist(n, ff, basedict)
    for i in smallprimes
        tmp = powsfunc(i, n, ff, basedict)
        bl = makeprod(bl, tmp, n, basedict)
    end
    return basedict
end
```

now, `dosigma3(100000, 0)` takes 0.5 seconds, for a factor of 1500 speedup over my original code, and a factor of 150 speedup over the other answer.

Also `dosigma3(10000000, 0` takes too long to run on JuliaBox, but on the aforementioned desktop it takes 130 seconds, so within a factor of two of the dumb implementation.

An examination of the code shows that the `makeprod` routine suffers from not having the various inputs sorted, which could result in faster termination. To make them faster, we can introduce a merge step, thus:

```
function domerge(l1, l2)
   newl = Int[]
   while true
        if isempty(l1)
            return vcat(l2, reverse(newl))
        elseif isempty(l2)
            return vcat(l1, reverse(newl))
        elseif l1[end]>l2[end]
                tmp = pop!(l1)
                push!(newl, tmp)
        else
                tmp = pop!(l2)
                push!(newl, tmp)
        end
    end
end

function makeprod2(l1, l2, nn, dd)
    res = Int[]
    for i in l1
         restmp = Int[]
         for j in l2 
            if i*j > nn
                break
            end
            dd[i*j] = dd[i] * dd[j]
            push!(restmp, i*j)
        end
        res = domerge(res, restmp)
    end
    return domerge(l1, domerge(l2, res))
end

function dosigma4(n, k)
    basedict = Dict{Int, BigInt}(1=>1)
    ff = thefunc(k)
    f2(a, b) = makeprod(a, b, n, basedict)
    smallprimes = reverse(primes(Int(ceil(sqrt(n))) -1))
    bl = biglist(n, ff, basedict)
    for i in smallprimes
        tmp = powsfunc(i, n, ff, basedict)
        bl = makeprod2(bl, tmp, n, basedict)
    end
    return basedict
end
```

However, this takes 15 seconds already for 100000, so I did not try it for 10000000, and indicates either my own incompetence in Julia (I am a novice, after all) or Julia's incompetence in managing memory. I very much look forward to insightful comments.

**UPDATE** a [simpler sieving implementation](https://github.com/igorrivin/juliant.git) speeds up the code by another factor of five, and introducing some more caching buys us another factor of 10(!), so computing the sigma_k for the first 10000000 (same machine as above, no parallelism used) takes between 28 (when done the first time) to 2 seconds (when done the second time. So, I guess intelligence is not entirely useless.